# How to find number from array react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

can we find match number from the array like

```
const array = [123,552,668,122,845]

//if we find 2 from the array then it shows all which have 2 like 123,552,122
```

it checks all index and finds that number include

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **filter** to run through the array & filter ones that do not contain '2'. Like this:

```
array.filter(a=> a.toString().indexOf("2")>-1)
```

`

```js
const array = [123,552,668,122,845]

var k = array.filter(a=> a.toString().indexOf("2")>-1)

console.log(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write  function like this:

```
function findNumbersWhichContainsValue(value, array) {
 return array.filter(s => s.toString().includes(value))
}
```

**Example:**

```
const array = [123,552,668,122,845];

findNumbersWhichContainsValue("2", array);
// return [123,552,122]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int n = '2'; //your number here
let arr = [123, 552, 668, 122, 845];
arr = arr.filter((s) => s.toString().includes(n));
console.log(arr);
// arr will equal [123,552,122]
```